# jquery .live problem with IE

Tags: javascript, focus, jquery

I have the following code which on focus hides a "dummy" password field (containing the word 'password') and shows a real password input field. It works fine in all browsers expect IE.

In IE, it works if I tab to the password field, but if I click on the password field it focuses correctly but I can't type into it.

```
    $("#passDummy").live('focus',function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#pass").show().focus();
    });
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8LvL/) to show it in practice...

If I use .focus and .blur rather than .live it also works, but I need to use .live in this case.

**EDIT**: I'm using jquery 1.5.1 (minified version) though it seem to be the case on all subsequent versions too.

Comment: what is the version of jquery you use ?

Comment: 1.5.1 minified... but it seems to be the case with all subsequent versions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Probably not the answer you want but here it is anyway; Upgrade to the latest jQuery.</strike>

I tested this with your Jsfiddle and IE8. Using jQuery 1.5.2 I reproduced your problem. Using jQuery 1.6.3 it works as expected.

Horrible workaround, but appears to work:

```
$("#pass").show();
setTimeout(function(){$('#pass').focus()},10);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/etmrR/

I assume this has something to do with the textfield not being shown quick enough to be given the focus in IE.

Comment: I don't have a problem with upgrading my jquery to the latest but the jsfiddle does use the latest and the problem is still there for me.

Comment: @Tom - weird becaiuse I swear I cant reproduce the problem with vlatest, but can reproduce it with 1.5.2 - I'll take another look.

Comment: Thanks. I have to double click in the textbox to get it to work. Double clicking is not ideal!

Comment: I would like to think there's a better way around this, but this is IE we're talking about so I have no doubt that there's no other way! I'll keep looking for a bit but give you the tick if I still can't find anything that's less of a workaround. Thanks